# regarding Changing CiscoAny connect Client GUI Text and message

Tags: firewall, cisco, asa, anyconnect

I tried changing from Configuration > Remote Access VPN > Network (Client) Access > AnyConnect Customization/Localization > GUI Text and Message and also from language localisation. But none of solution work for me.

Asa 9.14 and ASDM 7.17 and AnyConnect Client 4.10 is running on my system.

Can anyone help me in this regards?

Comment: For AnyConnect localization to work, corresponding Cisco published .mo file should be uploaded. Make sure your system localization matches with what is being configured on ASDM.

Answer (score 0):

Its working now. I have gone through below steps.

1. I have exported the AnyConnect template file from "Configuration>Remote Access VPN>Language Localization"
2. Modified the file using editor at my local machine according to my requirement.
3. Then imported the template in six different Language to "Configuration> Remote Access VPN> Network (Client) Access > AnyConnect Customization/Localization> GUI Text and Messages" this location

Its working now!